# Ping is not saving to file

Tags: cmd, ping

I try to type command:

```
start "xyz" ping xx.xx.xx.xx >> C:\Users\X\Desktop\t\xyz.txt
```

It creates empty file. 
What am i missing ? Thanks.

Comment: Based on  your example, I think this is a windows question.  You might have better luck tagging it for windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and you're right guycole i will remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that you redirect the output of `start` to the file. You have to "link" the redirection to the `cmd` instead.

Either (as Liturgist already answered) by escaping the `>>`:

```
start "xyz" cmd.exe /C ping localhost ^>^>xyz.txt
```

or by enclosing your "executed string" into quotes:

```
start "xyz" cmd.exe /C "ping localhost >>xyz.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the redirection characters.

```
start "xyz" cmd.exe /C ping localhost ^>^>xyz.txt
```